# Python - meshio: How to define vertex cells for point-only data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, hdf5, mesh

#### Problem

I have a 2D time-series data, and I want to save it as XMDF using meshio. The problem is, my mesh is just an array of points with associated point data, and I don't have any cell defined. As such, I tried to use the `"vertex"` cell type, which is a single-point cell, but it doesn't work. Meshio's documentation is kind of lacking, so I'm stuck.

#### Code

Following the two examples [on their Github page](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio), I did the following. I'm not sure how to define the cells correctly, as meshio doesn't document this properly.

```
# generate some data on a 10x10 mesh with 20 time steps (tested, works)
ts = np.arange(20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
data = np.empty((20, 10, 10))
for i, t in enumerate(ts):
    data[i] = np.sin((x + y) * t)
# data is a 3D NumPy array now with dimensions (20,10,10)

# generate list of points (tested, works)
points = [list(p) for p in zip(*(x.flat, y.flat,))]

# won't use cells, so define vertex cell (1 point per cell) <-- ???
cells = [("vertex", [i,]) for i in range(len(points))]

# as seen in meshio's documentation, write time series data
filename = "test.xdmf"
with meshio.xdmf.TimeSeriesWriter(filename) as writer:
    writer.write_points_cells(points, cells)
    for i, t in enumerate(ts):
        writer.write_data(t, point_data={"sin_city": data[i]})
```

#### Error

The above script produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ezio/Codes/gfield/_temp.py", line 103, in <module>
    writer.write_points_cells(points, cells)
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meshio/xdmf/time_series.py", line 284, in write_points_cells
    self.points(grid, points)
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meshio/xdmf/time_series.py", line 340, in points
    if points.shape[1] == 2:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I tried different combinations of converting some of the arrays used to NumPy array, but I couldn't find out the cause. I ask for your help.

#### Update:

After changing every used number array to NumPy arrays (credit to comments) - that is, inserting `points = np.array(points)` directly after `points` is defined, and changing the cell generator line to `cells = [("vertex", np.array([i,])) for i in range(len(points))]` - I still have a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ezio/Codes/gfield/_temp.py", line 105, in <module>
    writer.write_points_cells(points, cells)
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meshio/xdmf/time_series.py", line 285, in write_points_cells
    self.cells(cells, grid)
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meshio/xdmf/time_series.py", line 409, in cells
    [
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/meshio/xdmf/time_series.py", line 411, in <listcomp>
    np.insert(
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in insert
  File "/home/ezio/anaconda3/envs/radpolpy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4527, in insert
    axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, ndim)
numpy.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

(I also note that the documentation does not use NumPy arrays in the examples.)

Comment: `points` needs to be a 2D numpy array where the second dimension is 2.  You have a list of lists.  Just doing `points = np.array(points)` should be enough.

Comment: @TimRoberts It helped I think, but then I still have a different error. I updated the question accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well, `points.shape[1]` is a numpy function, so they must be assuming numpy for the points array.  In your new error, it is complaining that `cells` is a one dimensional array, and it expected 2.  Perhaps you should link to the documentation.

Comment: @TimRoberts I would, but meshio doesn't have a documentation apart from the linked github page. Anyway, the problem was, in hindsight obviously,  that I should've flatten my data as well. In any case I decided to abandod meshio as it doesn't fit my needs, and it's hard to work without any proper documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that:

1. I should've use NumPy arrays everywhere: even though meshio's example use Python lists, the xmdf module apparently can't handle those; and
2. I should've flatten the data as well (obviously). Also the cells should be be defined in a better way, though the original concept works too.

A working version of my code is:

```
# generate some data on a 10x10 mesh with 20 time steps (tested, works)
ts = np.arange(20)
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(10), np.arange(10))
data = np.empty((20, 10, 10))
for i, t in enumerate(ts):
    data[i] = np.sin((x + y) * t)
# data is a 3D NumPy array now with dimensions (20,10,10)

# generate list of points (tested, works)
points = [list(p) for p in zip(*(x.flat, y.flat,))]
points = np.array(points)  # add this

# won't use cells, so define vertex cell (1 point per cell)
cells = [("vertex", np.array([[i,] for i in range(len(points)])))]
# instead of cells = [("vertex", [i,]) for i in range(len(points))]

# as seen in meshio's documentation, write time series data
filename = "test.xdmf"
with meshio.xdmf.TimeSeriesWriter(filename) as writer:
    writer.write_points_cells(points, cells)
    for i, t in enumerate(ts):
        # here data[i] also should be flattened
        writer.write_data(t, point_data={"sin_city": data[i].flatten})
```